# How to change the expiration date for a self created Certificate Authority in keychain

Tags: certificate, keychain

I'm trying to create a Certificate Authority in Keychain on Mac using stored public & private keys.  The output CA has an expiration date of a year from the creation date.

I would like to increase the duration of the certificate validity.

I can do it on linux with this [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL) by the following command:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -out cacert.pem -outform PEM -days 1825
```

The command will create a certificate authority that expires in 5 years.

***Is it possible to do that using keychain or another method (changing some configuration files)? and HOW?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it on the first screen on the Certificate Assistant "Create Your Certificate Authority".  Just click the "Let me override defaults". Click "Continue" and the next screen has a box to fill in the validity duration.

There you go.