# How to change the Validity Period for a Certificate created by request certificate from certificate authority to upload to developer account

Tags: certificate, keychain, apple-developer

Im trying to create a p12 certificate from developer account with a higher expiration date. Currently all my p12 are only valid for 1 year. I believe it can be changed from Certificate Assistant. But not sure of the steps. Any insights would much appreciate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522222/extend-renew-a-p12-certificate-self-signed-expired. Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand that you cannot renew or modify the contents of a certificate once it is issued by a certification authority (CA). But I believe at the time of submitting a new CSR you can do that. based on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448167/how-to-change-the-expiration-date-for-a-self-created-certificate-authority-in-ke

Comment: @danu The answer you are referring to is regarding creating your own Certificate Authority, simply said, when you issue certificates yourself, but in this case you want a certificate issued by Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the validity period of an existing Apple Developer certificate or specify a custom validity period when requesting a new certificate.

The validity period of your certificate is governed by the `Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority`. More info in the [Certification Practice Statement](https://images.apple.com/certificateauthority/pdf/Apple_WWDR_CPS_v1.21.pdf).

As specified in [RFC2986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986), a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) does not provision a field for the requester to define a validity period. So technically there is no way to tell the Certificate Authority (CA) that you want a custom validity period.

To avoid confusion I will mention that [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/x509.html) does have a `-days` option to specify the certificate validity, but only in combination with the `-x509` option which issues a self-signed certificate for testing purposes.